# Static content return error 500 after upgrade to MVC 4

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc-4

We've been running a .Net 4 MVC 3 application without any problems and decided to upgrade to MVC 4 today. The MVC 4 version works great when I run it locally on my computer, but when published to the server (running IIS 7) it returns error code 500 for all css files and js files.

No other changes have been made to the application.

MVC 4 is not installed on the server (neither was MVC 3) so instead we deploy the necessary dlls using a _bin_deployableAssemblies folder.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was related to compression of the static files.
We'd added httpCompression (gzip) and urlCompression to our web.config some time ago (when we were still using MVC 3) but for some reason it didn't kick in until today I guess.

I tried publishing the application with MVC 3 again and got the same error which led to me finding the problem.